# This clamping circuit output is -ve compared to what is expected?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, oscillator, transient, diode-clamp

Clock Pulse of Vpeak =10. Providing that the first cycle is -ve why does the output in first is -20 then 0 then -20 and so on? I expected it to be 0 and 20.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What clamping circuit?

Comment: Review and update your circuit please. Also look at the capacitor as well as the 10 k resistor connected to the diode.  It might also assist if you point out what these components are supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about some simulation program such as LTspice, because that's the way they chose to define it.

If you want a 0 and 20 you define the amplitude as 10 and the DC offset as 10.